# incrementing a field in a table when insertion in another table occurs mongo axios

Tags: mongodb, axios

I have two tables:

```
Itinerary
      name
      dateStart
      dateEnd
      userEmail
      locationsId[]
      cityId[]
      userId
      usersId[]
```

and

```
Location
    name
    longitude
    latitude
    clicks
```

I want when I add an itinerary, to increment the clicks field of locations table, only for the locations added in locationsId

```
exports.create = (req, res) => {
    // Validate request
    if (!req.body.name && !req.body.dateStart && !req.body.dateEnd) {
      res.status(400).send({ message: "Content can not be empty!" });
      return;
    }
  
    // Create a Itinerary
    const itinerary = new Itinerary({
      name: req.body.name,
      dateStart: req.body.dateStart,
      dateEnd: req.body.dateEnd,
      userEmail: req.body.userEmail,
      locationsId: req.body.locationsId,
      cityId: req.body.cityId,
      userId:req.body.userId,
      usersId:req.body.usersId
    });
  
    // Save Itinerary in the database
    itinerary
      .save(itinerary)
      .then(data => {
        res.send(data);
        Location.findByIdAndUpdate(
          data.locationsId,
          {$inc: {clicks:1}}
                .then(data2=>{
                  res.send(data2)
                })
                .catch(err =>{
                  res.status(500).send({message:err.message})
                  
                })
        )
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).send({
          message:
            err.message || "Some error occurred while creating the Itinerary."
        });
      });
  };
```

this is what I have till now but it doesn't work when I want to see the Locations and I get an error that says:

node:internal/errors:490
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
^

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Comment: You have a `res.send({data})` line, but then you attempt to `.send()` again in the lines following that which you can't do

Comment: I just want to update the second table, not to get anything.Should I delete the second res.send? @user20042973